# How to step into a c++ std library function in gdb/gud

Tags: gdb, gud

This is most likely an issue with `g++`/`gdb`/other, but an indirect issue within Emacs nonetheless.

Whilst debugging, I would like for Emacs to step into the standard library implementation of the `overloaded << operator function called from object std::cout`.
As is shown in the series of screenshots when the current source file (in the source file window) switches from `main.cpp` to `funct.cpp` when function `funct()` is called:

**Screenshot 1**
Just starting the debugging session.
[image]

**Screenshot 2**
One `step` taken; thus changing the source file I'm looking at.
[image]

**Screenshot 3**
One `step` taken; `std::cout << "ok\n";` is completely stepped over; when I would like to be directed to another source file.
[image]

The command I used to compile the files:
`g++ -g -std=c++11 main.cpp funct.cpp`

If someone could guide me through step-by-step of how they got this to work, that would be a great example to learn from; or if any more information is needed (whether it be the system I'm using, file-paths, etc.), please ask away.

Comment: There's nothing you can do with Emacs that will change how this works, since you're just asking Emacs to ask gdb to step. Try compiling your program with `-Og -ggdb`, to ensure that you have the maximum amount of debugging information available.

Comment: Yep! You're the man db48x! Feel free to post this as an answer to the question, so that I can accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing you can do with Emacs that will change how this works, since you're just asking Emacs to ask gdb to step. Try compiling your program with `-Og -ggdb`, to ensure that you have the maximum amount of debugging information available.

And of course there are about a billion related options that you can use to control the amount of optimization the compiler does and the amount of debug information it includes. You should set aside a week to read through the gcc man page from top to bottom, so that you know them all. Have fun :)